# Android + Groovy + Android Annotation

Tags: android, groovy, android-annotations

i'm playing with android and android-annotiations, and why not play with groovy too... maybe to much :D

AndroidAnnotations, with help of APT (Android Processing Tools) generate helper class, that can be use in source code, and this source code compile before APT create...

Groovy its a great language that can run in Android, and with help of [swissknife](https://github.com/Arasthel/SwissKnife) can create a rapid apps, a few examples out there.

Its possible mix both approachs? I think not, but may i ask :)

See this code...

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'

...

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.batuypn:SmartConfigLibrary:v1.0.6'
```

The code

```
...
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

import batuypn.android.smartconfiglibrary.SmartConfigLibrary_
import batuypn.android.smartconfiglibrary.SmartConfigLibrary_.*

// @CompileStatic
class SmartConfigActivity extends Activity implements SmartConfigLibrary_.Callback {
    private SmartConfigLibrary_ smartConfigLibrary;
...
```

The error

> SmartConfigActivity.groovy: 16: unable to resolve class
>   SmartConfigLibrary_.Callback
>   @ line 16, column 1.    class
>   SmartConfigActivity extends Activity implements
>   SmartConfigLibrary_.Callback {    ^
>
> 1 error
>
> :compileDebugGroovy FAILED

Comment: Where SmartConfigLibrary_ is coming from?

Comment: From here... https://github.com/batuypn/SmartConfigLibrary

Comment: BTW, `SmartConfigLibrary_` should come with the dependency, i do not know why it can be found. Actually i never trusted jitpack.io...

Comment: Well, first, how many things i'm learning :D thanks all. Second, i think another player or not the dependency its packed as .aar and inside classes.jar there its a 

package batuypn.android.smartconfiglibrary;
public final class SmartConfigLibrary_ extends SmartConfigLibrary

maybe need import int another way?

Comment: Share your project in GH, i will check it out.

Comment: https://github.com/josejuanmontiel/SmartConfigGroovy Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since Gradle 2.5,  you can use "annotation processing" on Groovy source code. This is technically not Groovy processing, because actually Gradle forces the Groovy compiler to create Java stubs, then processes that stubs. The processors will create Java sources, which will be compiled with Groovy in joint compilation. This means you can only use annotations on Groovy constructs which have equivalents in the Java language. But basically this should not be a problem, since processors designed to work with Java. Also you can only use this feature to generate new classes, not modify existing ones, like lombok does in a really hackish way. From a user point of view this Groovy processing should be transparent despite of the technic behind it.

I created an example project which demonstrates this: https://github.com/WonderCsabo/androidannotations/tree/groovyExample/examples/gradle

**EDIT:** the `android-apt` plugin now supports Groovy Android processing, so the Gradle configuration is much easier. I changed the example above to utilize `android-apt`.

You can also add Java sources and process them, the generated classes will be available for Groovy.

Comment: Compilation of any Groovy classes which implement traits seem to break, probably because what you said about "...you can only use annotations on Groovy constructs which have equivalents in the Java language".

Answer (score 0):

In case melix misunderstood you...

If you use annotations on Java code to produce new classes and want to use those in Groovy, then this is possible. An example is using Dagger2 and Groovy code that uses classes generated from annotated Java code.

Comment: Can you show me some example of this? The only thing i could find was this... https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/issues/32 but it's slightly diferent, because use @anotation inside groovy code... and i'm extending groovy class with generated code... i'll push a complete code with example later, answering comment of melix

Comment: I would have shown the same example.This is too new too have many such examples available atm. But the smal difference should not matter.

Comment: How it is done is like this: groovy code is translated to Java stubs, including all annotations. Then javac is called with those stubs, and the annotation processor is run together with javac. Then groovy is compiled against the newly produced classes. At this point all the classes produced by the annotation processor should be available as well. If not, then because something with paths is wrong

Comment: What the does not work is modifying the groovy classes itself through dagger. But afaik this is not the case for dagger, unless I misunderstood things.

Comment: I created an example and commented on melix answer: https://github.com/WonderCsabo/androidannotations/tree/groovyExample/examples/gradle

Answer (score 0):

About the exact problem:

Change this:

```
class SmartConfigActivity extends Activity implements SmartConfigLibrary_.Callback {
    private SmartConfigLibrary_ smartConfigLibrary;
```

to this:

```
class SmartConfigActivity extends Activity implements SmartConfigLibrary.Callback {
    private SmartConfigLibrary smartConfigLibrary;
```

This way your project can be (almost) built. To fully fix the problem, i suggest to build the project from scratch based on [my example](https://github.com/WonderCsabo/androidannotations/tree/groovyExample/examples/gradle).

Comment: Well, works, can you explain? Your example use anotation, and not extends, and this its documented and supported in gradle (from 2.4 ;) but i use java 1.8 and have this error ... :dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)

Comment: and change dependecy to AAR.... compile 'com.github.batuypn:SmartConfigLibrary:1.0.6@aar'

Comment: @accreativos you are mixing too much things in the beginning... You cannot use Java 8 with Android, it is not supported. Change back to Java 7.

Comment: jajaja you are right :D i ask how to tell gradle + android compile with 1.7 profile.. y try android {compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  } but no change...

Answer (score -1):

No. Android Annotations works on Java sources only. For Groovy sources, you must use SwissKnife.

Comment: Well... i use http://mariogarcia.github.io/grooid-templates to create a android-groovy template (may you know :) and i want to use this library https://github.com/batuypn/SmartConfigLibrary build on top of https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations and THIS its the example: https://github.com/josejuanmontiel/SmartConfigGroovy code mixing this. As you comment in https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/issues/32 its for java view groovy class.. but here i need groovy see FIRST APT-generated class

Comment: This is not true. AA actually works on Groovy sources. Check out [this](https://github.com/WonderCsabo/androidannotations/tree/groovyExample/examples/gradle) example!

Comment: Technically it doesn't work on Groovy sources. It may work on Java sources produced by the Groovy stub compiler.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the refinement. But I guess this is more a usage question ☺. Sorry for the rushed down vote.